# Andres' algorithm - Draw a circular chromatic gradiation

Tags: java, image, trigonometry

I wrote a program which draws a circle colored thanks to a chromatic gradation, using the Andres' algorithm. Here is an execution's result :

[image: Chromatic circular gradiation]

Now I would want to shift this gradation. For example, I would want the red to begin at the right of the circle. Or at 70°. Etc.

**So I have a shift, in radians. And I must use it in my Andres' algorithm.**
But I don't understand how. However, I see two ways to do that :

1. Either I change the Andres' algorithm, I mean I change the coordinates of each pixel of each octant (= I change the circle's drawing) ;
2. Or I really shift the gradation and not the drawing.

**I would prefer the solution number one.** And I know it will make use of **trigonometry**. But my skills are too bad and I really need your help please...

**Here is the source of my Andres' implementation.** If you need it, I can also show you the code of my gradation-function. Thank you in advance.

*NB : the most important part is just below the line `while (y >= x)` (id est : the octants' coordinates).*

```
case "Andres' algorithm":
w = 2 * Math.PI;

for(double current_thickness = 0; current_thickness < this.thickness; current_thickness++) {
    x = 0;
    y = (int) (radius + current_thickness);
    double d = radius + current_thickness - 1;

    while (y >= x) {
        double octant_1_x = x0 + x, octant_1_y = y0 + y;
        double octant_2_x = x0 + y, octant_2_y = y0 + x;
        double octant_3_x = x0 - x, octant_3_y = y0 + y;
        double octant_4_x = x0 - y, octant_4_y = y0 + x;
        double octant_5_x = x0 + x, octant_5_y = y0 - y;
        double octant_6_x = x0 + y, octant_6_y = y0 - x;
        double octant_7_x = x0 - x, octant_7_y =  y0 - y;
        double octant_8_x = x0 - y, octant_8_y = y0 - x;

        max_counter++;

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_1 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_1_y - y0, octant_1_x - x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_1_x, octant_1_y, Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_1[0], rgb_gradation_octant_1[1], rgb_gradation_octant_1[2]))); // octant n°1

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_2 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_2_y - y0, octant_2_x - x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_2_x, octant_2_y, Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_2[0], rgb_gradation_octant_2[1], rgb_gradation_octant_2[2])));

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_3 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_3_y - y0, octant_3_x - x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_3_x, octant_3_y, Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_3[0], rgb_gradation_octant_3[1], rgb_gradation_octant_3[2])));

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_4 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_4_y - y0, octant_4_x - x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_4_x, octant_4_y, Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_4[0], rgb_gradation_octant_4[1], rgb_gradation_octant_4[2]))); // octant n°4

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_5 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_5_y-y0, octant_5_x-x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_5_x, octant_5_y, Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_5[0], rgb_gradation_octant_5[1], rgb_gradation_octant_5[2]))); // octant n°5

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_6 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_6_y-y0, octant_6_x-x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_6_x, octant_6_y, Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_6[0], rgb_gradation_octant_6[1], rgb_gradation_octant_6[2])));

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_7 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_7_y-y0, octant_7_x-x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_7_x, octant_7_y, Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_7[0], rgb_gradation_octant_7[1], rgb_gradation_octant_7[2])));

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_8 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_8_y-y0, octant_8_x-x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_8_x, octant_8_y, Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_8[0], rgb_gradation_octant_8[1], rgb_gradation_octant_8[2]))); // octant n°8

        if (d >= 2 * x) {
            d -= 2 * x + 1;
            x++;
        } else if (d < 2 * (radius + thickness - y)) {
            d += 2 * y - 1;
            y--;
        } else {
            d += 2 * (y - x - 1);
            y--;
            x++;
        }

    }
}

gui.getImageAnimation().setMax(max_counter*8);
break;
```

Comment: You could always cheat and just rotate an image of the result, rather than calculating everything. ;)

Comment: I know haha but I don't really want =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2 dimensions, you can achieve rotation with the following formulas:

`x' = x cos f - y sin f`

`y' = y cos f + x sin f`

---

Instead of repeating the transformation in every Pixel instantiation, you could write a helper that creates a rotated pixel and returns it. I meant something like:

```
Pixel rotated_pixel (double x, double y, Pixel rotation_center, Color color, double angle) {
    double x0 = rotation_center.x,
    y0 = rotation_center.y, // Oh god I hope I'm not also wrong about the field names now
    sinw = Math.sin(angle), cosw = Math.cos(angle),
    x_rot = x0 + (x-x0)*cosw - (y-y0)*sinw,
    y_rot = y0 + (y-y0)*cosw + (x-x0)*sinw;
    return new Pixel(x_rot, y_rot, color); // or smth
}
```

Then you can use it like `updates.add(rotated_pixel(x,y,whatever));`

I'm sorry that I cannot check the validity of this code; I don't currently have access to a computer with Java.

Comment: So it would be for example : ` double octant_1_x = x0 + x * Math.cos(shift), octant_1_y = y0 + y * Math.sin(shift); ` ? I can also write these coefs in `new Pixel(...)` ?

Comment: `double octant_1_x = x0*Math.cos(shift) - y0*Math.sin(shift), octant_1_y = y0*Math.cos(shift) + x0*Math.sin(shift);` seems to me to be the correct formula.

Comment: Wow it seems to rewrite quite consequently the Andres' algorithm ; do you think I can avoid modifying these coordinates' definitions, and just change the `Pixel` instanciations ? As : `new Pixel(octant_1_x * Math.cos(shift) - octant_1_y * Math.sin(shift), octant_1_y * Math.cos(shift) + octant_1_x * Math.sin(shift), Color.color(...) ` ?

Comment: How about writing a helper function like `Pixel rotate(Pixel() p)`?

Comment: A method which whose aim would be to rotate a pixel ? I don't understand what does mean "to rotate a pixel" and how it could be useful to rotate my circle ? If you think I can just modify the `Pixel` instanciations as showed you, I believe it's would be perfect :)

Comment: I mean instead of repeating the transformation in every Pixel instantiation, you could write a helper that creates a rotated pixel and returns it. I meant something like:

 Pixel rotated_pixel (double x, double y, Color color, double angle) {
 double x_rot = x*Math.cos(angle) - y*Math.cos(angle),
 y_rot = y*Math.cos(angle) + x*Math.cos(angle);
 return new Pixel(x_rot, y_rot, color); // or something
 }

Then you can use it like `updates.add(rotated_pixel(x,y,whatever));`

I'm sorry that I cannot check the validity of this code; I don't currently have access to a computer with Java.

Comment: Ah ok, yes you're perfectly right. I will try this. If it works, I'll tell you ! Thank you !

Comment: Sorry I couldn't format it properly :) I modified the original answer to include the code.

Comment: Haha no problem ! Thank you again. Just a question : you don't use `Math.sin` finally ?

Comment: Sorry, typo! Fixing the original question in a minute.

Comment: heum it doesn't seem to work : indeed it shifts the circle, but doesn't rotate it (so it doesn't rotate the gradiation) =/

Comment: These are the formulas for rotation around (0,0). If you want to rotate around (x0, y0); so you should update the formula as: `(...) x_rot = x0 + (x-x0)*cosw - (y-y0)*sinw, y_rot = y0 + (y-y0)*cosw + (x-x0)*sinw (...)`. Then again, there can be a typo in my code; I cannot test it at the moment.

Comment: Ah yes indeed it works ! There is still a little problem : some gaps appear when I rotate the circle, do you think it's because of a loss of precision (due to a cast for example), or is it "normal" ? Here is an image : http://imgur.com/BcAsP9n

Comment: Probably; but I'm only speculating. Rotating the colors with a similar approach *might* give you better results, as the positions of the pixels will be fixed.

Comment: Ok, I don't really want to change the gradation itself, it could be quite more difficult to do in my code. But thank you for having found the solution ! Would you recommend me some books about trigo ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kubuzetto , the code below allows me to draw a circle taking account of a shift, expressed in radians. I mean its drawing begins at a certain angle (which is the shift). I still use Andres.

**The only new problem with this solution is that gaps appear when the circle is rotated (ie. : when there is a shift).**

Indeed :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv6rG.jpg

I thought it was because of a cast which would have decreased the precision of the coordinates, but it's not the case.

If someone see why there is this problem, it would be fine !

```
/**
 * Constructs a Pixel taking account of a shift and near the position (x0 ; y0)
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @param color
 * @param angle
 * @param x0
 * @param y0
 */
Pixel(double x, double y, Color color, double angle, double x0, double y0) {
    this.x = (int) (x0 + (x-x0) * Math.cos(angle) - (y-y0) * Math.sin(angle));
    this.y = (int) (y0 + (y-y0) * Math.cos(angle) + (x-x0) * Math.sin(angle));
    this.color = color;
}
```

**And the Andres' algorithm :**

```
case "Andres' algorithm":
w = 2 * Math.PI;

for(double current_thickness = 0; current_thickness < this.thickness; current_thickness++) {
    x = 0;
    y = (int) (radius + current_thickness);
    double d = radius + current_thickness - 1;

    while (y >= x) {
        double octant_1_x = x0 + x, octant_1_y = y0 + y;
        double octant_2_x = x0 + y, octant_2_y = y0 + x;
        double octant_3_x = x0 - x, octant_3_y = y0 + y;
        double octant_4_x = x0 - y, octant_4_y = y0 + x;
        double octant_5_x = x0 + x, octant_5_y = y0 - y;
        double octant_6_x = x0 + y, octant_6_y = y0 - x;
        double octant_7_x = x0 - x, octant_7_y =  y0 - y;
        double octant_8_x = x0 - y, octant_8_y = y0 - x;

        max_counter++;

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_1 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_1_y - y0, octant_1_x - x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_1_x, octant_1_y,
                Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_1[0], rgb_gradation_octant_1[1], rgb_gradation_octant_1[2]),
                circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0)); // octant n°1

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_2 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_2_y - y0, octant_2_x - x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_2_x, octant_2_y,
                Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_2[0], rgb_gradation_octant_2[1], rgb_gradation_octant_2[2]),
                circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0));

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_3 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_3_y - y0, octant_3_x - x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_3_x, octant_3_y,
                Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_3[0], rgb_gradation_octant_3[1], rgb_gradation_octant_3[2]),
                circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0));

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_4 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_4_y - y0, octant_4_x - x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_4_x, octant_4_y,
                Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_4[0], rgb_gradation_octant_4[1], rgb_gradation_octant_4[2]),
                circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0)); // octant n°4

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_5 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_5_y-y0, octant_5_x-x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_5_x, octant_5_y,
                Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_5[0], rgb_gradation_octant_5[1], rgb_gradation_octant_5[2]),
                circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0)); // octant n°5

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_6 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_6_y-y0, octant_6_x-x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_6_x, octant_6_y,
                Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_6[0], rgb_gradation_octant_6[1], rgb_gradation_octant_6[2]),
                circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0));

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_7 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_7_y-y0, octant_7_x-x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_7_x, octant_7_y,
                Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_7[0], rgb_gradation_octant_7[1], rgb_gradation_octant_7[2]),
                circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0));

        double[] rgb_gradation_octant_8 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_8_y-y0, octant_8_x-x0) + Math.PI, w);
        updates.add(new Pixel(octant_8_x, octant_8_y,
                Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_8[0], rgb_gradation_octant_8[1], rgb_gradation_octant_8[2]),
                circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0)); // octant n°8

        if (d >= 2 * x) {
            d -= 2 * x + 1;
            x++;
        } else if (d < 2 * (radius + thickness - y)) {
            d += 2 * y - 1;
            y--;
        } else {
            d += 2 * (y - x - 1);
            y--;
            x++;
        }

    }
}

gui.getImageAnimation().setMax(max_counter*8);
break;
```